# maximum number of testers on google play alpha/beta testing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, beta-testing

My app has not been released yet. What is the maximum number of alpha/beta testers I can have testing my app through Google Play? For iOS it's 1000 external testers per build. What's the Google Play limit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no effective limit (although there are [membership invite limitations for Google Groups](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6099642?hl=en)): Facebook, for example, uses alpha and beta channels for millions of users.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good link for reference https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en
Basically: Internal test: manage up to 100 testers, Closed test and Open test: there's no limitation