# Is there a way to distribute windows store app privately without sideloading

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, sideloading

I went through Windows Store App and distribution models. I want to distribute my application privately (not want to publish it in store). But [Sideloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn832613.aspx) does not seems to be option either as it is very expensive ($3000). Is there a license or way for this?

Windows Phone Store seems to [hiding app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj619160(v=vs.105).aspx) from store listing. Is that available for Store Apps?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is it only for the beginning, i.e. alpha or beta?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Horne Not for begining. Its for long usage.

Comment: The perpetual beta is an option.  Google has being doing that for years. :)

Comment: @Anthony Horne I don't think such option exists for Windows Store. If you sideload as developer testing, it will expire in one month.

Comment: I have a app running in beta mode in windows store and it has been running for a few months already - it was not side-loaded, it was done through the app store, but invite based - like the android store. (Cannot speak for IOS, yet..)

Comment: See my updated answer image.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Use Windows Side-loading though volume license agreements (then sideloading only costs you $100 for unlimited devices - see : http://microsoft-news.com/you-can-buy-windows-8-1-enterprise-sideloading-rights-for-an-unlimited-number-of-devices-for-100/)
2. Run perpetual beta, whereby you invite users to "test" or use your application in the app store (but it is hidden).

[image]

Comment: I've heard there is a limit to the number of beta users allowed. Is this true?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx - essentially as many users as you can send out links / emails.    Same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/26665051/1662973 for Google.  Don't know about IOS - as I am yet to deploy.

Comment: I've done the iOS distribution for both Beta testing and Enterprise Distribution but I'm running in to issues signing for Enterprise Distribution on the Surface finding out the best way to do it.